# Solve this inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

We have this inequality :

$1-x^2-\log x \ge 0$

How we can solve this inequality ? (Note : It is natural $\log$)

(In general , I have problem with inequalities involving logarithms and exponents functions.)

Comment: what kind of $\log$ it is?

Comment: It is natural $\log$ .

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1-x^2-\log(x)$.Compute $f'(x)$ and analyze it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Are you sure derivatives are necesary here? I think it's easier to just look at what happens to the expression on $(0,1)$ and what happens on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @5xum. Yes for sure. However, the derivative is quite interestin to look at. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x > 1$. Then $1-x^2<0$ and $\log x>0$. In this case the inequality is false.

Let $0<x < 1$.  Then $1-x^2 > 0$ and and $\log x < 0$. In this case the inequality is true.

The case $x=1$ should be clear.

Comment: I know it is obvious that intersection point is $x = 1$ but is there any algebraic way to find out this point ? In the other words , I want to solve $1-x^2 - \log x = 0$

Comment: Let $f(x):=1-x^2-\log x$. Then $f(1)=0$. Now suppose that there is $x_0$ such that $x_0>0$, $x_0 \ne 1$ and $f(x_0)=0$. By Rolle, there is $x_1$ such that $f'(x_1)=0$. This leeds to $2x_1^2+1=0$ Contadiction

Comment: Thank you a lot , but I have another question . What is your mean by this ($:=$) symbol ?

Comment: $f(x):=1-x^2-\log x$ means: the function $f$ is defined by ....

Comment: So , What is the difference between $:=$ and $=$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If the $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm (i.e., base $e$), then

**Hint**:

- What is the sign of $\log x$?
- When $\log x$ is negative, what is the sign of the expression?
- What about when $\log x$ is positive?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we must have $x > 0$ for $\log x$ to be defined. Next, notice that $1 - x^2 - \log x = 0$ if and only if $1 - x^2 \geq \log x$.

The function $f_1(x) = 1 - x^2$ is strictly decreasing for the interval $(0;\infty)$ while $f_2(x) = \log x$ is strictly increasing for the same interval. We have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_1(x) = 1$, while $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f_2(x) = -\infty$.

The graphs of $f_1$ and $f_2$ intersect at $x=1$, since $1 - 1^2 = \log 1 = 0$. We must therefore have that $0 < x \leq 1$ is the required solution.

Comment: I know it is obvious that intersection point is $x = 1$ but is there any algebraic way to find out this point ? In the other words , I want to solve $1-x^2 - \log x = 0$

Answer (score 1):

if we have $$f(x)=1-x^2-ln(x)$$ then we get $$\lim_{ x \to 0}f(x)=+\infty$$ and $$f'(x)$$ is given by $$f'(x)=-2x-\frac{1}{x}$$ for $$x>0$$ and 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=-\infty$$ thus we have only one intersection point with the $$x$$ axis whis is given by $x=1$

Comment: I know it is obvious that intersection point is $x = 1$ but is there any algebraic way to find out this point ?

Comment: In the other words , I want to solve $1-x^2 - \log x = 0$